# C++ Shared pointers. How can I change the underlying object's pointer for all copies?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a strange situation with virtual classes and I need design help.

1. The objects do work on destruction,
2. The objects are stored in a vector, but I need to get the object or a reference to it out of the vector, change it, and have that change reflected in ALL 'copies' of the object,
3. I'd like the objects to be copyable.

I have a solution, but I am looking for a better one.  This is the code I've written that accomplishes what I am looking for, but it depends on pointers to pointers to pointers.

I feel like if I could just directly manipulate the underlying data pointer of the shared pointer, I could get away with one less layer of abstraction.

I would like to do this with one InterfaceWrapper, not two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void WriteIt() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() { }
};

class Foo : public Interface
{
  void WriteIt() { printf ("Foo\n"); }
};

class Bar : public Interface
{
  void WriteIt() { printf ("Bar\n"); }
};

// This class wraps Interface so we can call WriteIt on desctruction
// I'd like to do this in the Interface class, but you can't call virtual methods during destruction.
class InterfaceWrapper : public std::unique_ptr<Interface>
{
  public:
  InterfaceWrapper(Interface * i) : std::unique_ptr<Interface>(i) { }
  ~InterfaceWrapper() { (*this)->WriteIt(); }
};

// This class provides counted destruction to InterfaceWrapper
class InterfaceWrapper2
{
  public:
    InterfaceWrapper2 () : _ptr(new InterfaceWrapper(new Foo)) { }

    void MakeBar() { _ptr->reset(new Bar); }

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<InterfaceWrapper> _ptr;
};
    
int main (void)
{
  std::vector<InterfaceWrapper2> thing_vector;

  // The default implementation will, print "Foo" on destruction.
  InterfaceWrapper2 thing;

  // That destructor should only happen once for all copies of 'thing'
  thing_vector.push_back(thing);

  // MakeBar changes the virtual implementation so it prints "Bar" instead of "Foo"
  thing.MakeBar();

  // When destructors happen, the program should just print "Bar" once.

  return 0;
}
```

Anything is welcome, but I particularly interested in solutions which work on C++03 using boost (my example is C++11 but my 'real' code is C++03 using boost::shared_ptr).

## CLARIFICATION

I am basically looking for a better way to implement InterfaceWrapper2 in my example code.  `main()` is the best explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.  Just remember the behavior is stuck in those virtual classes.

Comment: `Interface` must have a virtual destructor otherwise the use of `unique_ptr<Interface>` to hold a `Foo` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: _"and have that change reflected in ALL 'copies' of the object"_ Then they're not copies...

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "ALL 'copies' of the object,"  ?   If you have a `shared_ptr` there is only one copy of the object being shared; and lots of `shared_ptr` referencing it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it sounds like he wants to have `shared_ptr<Interface>`, however have it so that if one of these `shared_ptr` has `reset` called on it, then all other `shared_ptr` that were pointing to the same object also are reset to the new object.   (which isn't possible of course, so there has to be two levels of indirection)

Comment: @MattMcNabb My code's main() method best describes what I need.  Basically, I need a class that behaves how InterfaceWrapper2 does, which has to build on top of the Interface class.

Comment: @QuestionC if your code appears to be working I'd suggest going with it (after fixing the virtual destructor)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hence the quotation marks.  If you look at my main() method, I make a copy of an InterfaceWrapper2 object, and calling a method on one changes both copies.

Comment: Do you just want a shared handle?

Comment: @QuestionC: I'll rephrase: then they _can't_ be copies.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Maybe?  I need a handle that reference counts, calls a virtual method on destruction, and I can change that virtual method at runtime.

Comment: Why not save the function pointer in the base class and call it in the destructor as long as the function doesn't involve members of derived classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing from [sehe's brilliant insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260944/315052), this version gives you something that is closer to what you can do within C++.2003:

```
class InterfaceWrapper {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Interface> UI;
    std::shared_ptr<UI> p_;
public:
    InterfaceWrapper () : p_(std::make_shared<UI>(new Foo)) {}
    ~InterfaceWrapper () { if (p_.unique()) (*p_)->WriteIt(); }
    void MakeBar() { p_->reset(new Bar); }
    const UI & operator -> () { return *p_.get(); }
};
```

Instead of a custom deleter, I chose to add a conditional within the destructor of `InterfaceWrapper`. This allowed the constructor to use `std::make_shared`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the `w()` accessor accomplishes. Oh wait, you replaced the inner unique_ptr with another std::shared_ptr (but stealthily) to remove the extra type and uncopyability? I wonder when this trick would be useful

Comment: In fact you don't re-use it. There's two instances of `shared_ptr<Interface>` involved, just not as named members of the class (one is bungling "outside the vehicle" tethered via an obscure dynamic spell). In that case, I'd say **[this simplified version](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9357565/)** is far superior, while less locking/refcounting overhead, no dynamic casting, no virtual destructor for the wrapper. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cc8c4687ff71ce6)**

Comment: @sehe, that's pretty slick!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

**Update 3**

If you want to keep the Interface machinery, the following is a pretty succinct way to write the wrapper by just composing standard library features:

```
class InterfaceWrapper {
    using UI = std::unique_ptr<Interface>;

    std::shared_ptr<UI> _sui {new UI{new Foo}, [](UI*p){ (*p)->WriteIt(); delete p; }};

public:
    void MakeBar() { _sui->reset(new Bar); }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cc8c4687ff71ce6)**

**Update 2**

1. After realizing that an `std::function<>` is already a dynamic, single-function, mutable interface that can be bound to any stateful functor, I thought of the following simplified version:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b66bd1ecbe89a25d)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <memory>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   struct dynamic_release {
       template <typename F> dynamic_release(F&& f) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) { }
       template <typename F> dynamic_release& operator=(F&& f) 
           { _f = std::forward<F>(f); return *this; }

       ~dynamic_release() { _f(); }
     private:
       std::function<void()> _f;
   };

   void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
   void do_bar() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }

   int main(void) {
       using InterfaceWrapper = std::shared_ptr<dynamic_release>;
       using Thing = InterfaceWrapper::element_type;

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>(do_foo);

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Foo" once

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>(do_foo);

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);

           *thing = do_bar; // Prints nothing

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Bar" once
   }
   ```
2. To enable optimizations in case you want to achieve more efficiency with state-less functors too, add a `basic_dynamic_release` template that allows to use different functor types (like, e.g. `void(*)()`):

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd8a75b528c2f3ac)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <memory>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace detail {

       template <typename InterfaceCallable>
       struct basic_dynamic_release {
           basic_dynamic_release() = default;

           template <typename F> basic_dynamic_release(F&& f) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) { }
           template <typename F> basic_dynamic_release& operator=(F&& f) 
               { _f = std::forward<F>(f); return *this; }

           ~basic_dynamic_release() { _f(); }
       private:
           InterfaceCallable _f;
       };
   }

   using dynamic_release = detail::basic_dynamic_release<std::function<void()>>;

   #include <vector>

   void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
   void do_bar() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }

   int main(void) {
       using InterfaceWrapper = std::shared_ptr<detail::basic_dynamic_release<void(*)(void)>>;
       using Thing = InterfaceWrapper::element_type;

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>(do_foo);

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Foo" once

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>(do_foo);

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);

           *thing = do_bar; // Prints nothing

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Bar" once
   }
   ```
3. To allow for default constructed instances to have a well defined implementation of the interface, adding a factory (this is to make it very generic):

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91750d8d020f65e2)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <memory>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace detail {

       template <typename T> struct default_construction final {
           T operator()() const { return {}; }
       };

       template <typename InterfaceCallable, typename Factory = default_construction<InterfaceCallable> >
       struct basic_dynamic_release {
           basic_dynamic_release() = default;

           template <typename F> basic_dynamic_release(F&& f) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) { }
           template <typename F> basic_dynamic_release& operator=(F&& f) 
               { _f = std::forward<F>(f); return *this; }

           ~basic_dynamic_release() { _f(); }
       private:
           InterfaceCallable _f = Factory()();
       };

       using dynamic_interface = std::function<void()>;
       template <typename Factory = default_construction<dynamic_interface> >
       using dynamic_release   = basic_dynamic_release<dynamic_interface, Factory>;
   }

   #include <vector>

   void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
   void do_bar() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }

   struct foo_default { detail::dynamic_interface operator()() const { return do_foo; } };

   int main(void) {
       using InterfaceWrapper = std::shared_ptr<detail::dynamic_release<foo_default> >;
       using Thing = InterfaceWrapper::element_type;

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>();

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Foo" once

       {
           std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;

           auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>();

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
           thing_vector.push_back(thing);

           *thing = &do_bar; // Prints nothing

           thing_vector.push_back(thing);
       } // prints "Bar" once
   }
   ```

---

### Old answer

The old answer favoured static polymorphism using `boost::variant`, at the cost of being somewhat more complex the manage, but with greater flexibility:

> I opted to replace the dynamic polymorphism with static polymorphism, which removes the extra allocation, which also takes with it the lifetime management (what used to be the `unique_ptr`).
>
> I think this makes resulting solution a bit simplified, and at the same time more generic (naturally provides some extension points).
>
> **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d3ae6fec24ede18)</kbd>**
>
> ```
> #include <boost/variant.hpp>
> #include <memory>
> #include <iostream>
>
> namespace nature { // detail namespace
>     template <typename> struct Nature;
>     template<> struct Nature<struct FooTag> { void do_it() { std::cout << "Foo" << "\n"; } };
>     template<> struct Nature<struct BarTag> { void do_it() { std::cout << "Bar" << "\n"; } };
>
>     using FooNature = Nature<FooTag>;
>     using BarNature = Nature<BarTag>;
>
>     using AnyNature = boost::variant<FooNature, BarNature>;
>
>     struct Holder {
>         AnyNature held;
>         ~Holder() { DoIt()(held); }
>
>       private:
>         struct DoIt : boost::static_visitor<> {
>             void operator()(AnyNature& any)                  const { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, any); }
>             template <typename N> void operator()(N& nature) const { return nature.do_it(); }
>         };
>     };
>
> }
>
> #include <vector>
>
> int main(void) {
>     using InterfaceWrapper = std::shared_ptr<nature::Holder>;
>     using Thing = InterfaceWrapper::element_type;
>
>     {
>         std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;
>
>         auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>(); // FooNature is default
>
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>     } // prints "Foo" once
>
>     {
>         std::vector<InterfaceWrapper> thing_vector;
>
>         auto thing = std::make_shared<Thing>();
>
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>
>         thing->held = nature::BarNature {}; // prints nothing
>
>         thing_vector.push_back(thing);
>     } // prints "Bar" once
> }
> ```
>
> Prints
>
> ```
> Foo
> Bar
> ```

Comment: Not quite.  "Foo" should not print when `set_bar(thing);` is called.

Comment: @QuestionC Thinking things over some more, I came up with a greatly simplified version. I have included progressively more feature-rich versions in the hopes that you will find the one that's right for you (and see how I'd evolve the design of such contraptions)

Comment: Added a third update for the solution in ~3 lines of code that would be a clear winner IFF you want to stick to the virtual interfaces. I hope you like it